# Suppress RequiredAttribute validation for the JsonMediaTypeFormatter in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, json.net

Assuming I sent the following request to my API:

```
POST http://localhost:4940/api/cars HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:4940
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 44

{"Make":"Make1","Year":2010,"Price":10732.2}
```

And I have the following Car class definition:

```
public class Car {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 500000)]
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

The response I got back is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcRHJvcGJveFxCb29rc1xQcm9XZWJBUEkuU2FtcGxlc1xDaGFwdGVyMTNcRGF0YUFubm90YXRpb25WYWxpZGF0aW9uQXR0cmlidXRlc1NhbXBsZVxEYXRhQW5ub3RhdGlvblZhbGlkYXRpb25BdHRyaWJ1dGVzU2FtcGxlXGFwaVxjYXJz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Sep 2012 11:38:58 GMT
Content-Length: 182

{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"car":["Required property 'Model' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 44."],"car.Model":["The Model field is required."]}}
```

Here is the more readable form of the message body:

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "car": [
            "Required property 'Model' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 44."
        ],
        "car.Model":[
            "The Model field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also have one additional error message for car and I am guessing the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` performs validation as well and it fails to perform the read action.

Is this the issue here? Is there any way I can suppress the validation at the JsonMediaTypeFormatter level? I don't want the formatter to perform validation because the validation is also performed by the `IBodyModelValidator` after the formatter reads the message body.

**Edit:**

I debugged the source code and it tuns out the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` throws an error if a Property is marked with Required and not supplied. the following code is a part from the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`:

```
// Error must always be marked as handled
// Failure to do so can cause the exception to be rethrown at every recursive level and overflow the stack for x64 CLR processes
jsonSerializer.Error += (sender, e) =>
{
    Exception exception = e.ErrorContext.Error;
    formatterLogger.LogError(e.ErrorContext.Path, exception);
    e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
```

and this triggers the `ModelStateFormatterLogger.LogError` method which puts the error inside the `ModelState`:

```
public void LogError(string errorPath, Exception exception)
{
    if (errorPath == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("errorPath");
    }
    if (exception == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("exception");
    }

    string key = ModelBindingHelper.ConcatenateKeys(_prefix, errorPath);
    _modelState.AddModelError(key, exception);
}
```

I am still unable to suppress this behavior.

Comment: In which release you got this response? I'm not having this issue in Webapi 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your question originally.
OK here is what you need to do:

Create a class deriving from the original `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` and set a custom `IRequiredMemberSelector`

```
public class MyJsonMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public MyJsonMediaTypeFormatter() : base()
        {
            RequiredMemberSelector = new MyRequiredMemberSelector();
        }
    }
```

In this custom `IRequiredMemberSelector` just define all properties to be not required.

```
public class MyRequiredMemberSelector : IRequiredMemberSelector
{
    public bool IsRequiredMember(System.Reflection.MemberInfo member)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now replace the default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` with the customized one and there you go.

Comment: thanks! replacing the `IRequiredMemberSelector` on the formatter would be better: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.RequiredMemberSelector`. I also find `JsonContractResolver` so useless. Directly using `DefaultContractResolver` would also solve the problem. Only useful thing that the `JsonContractResolver` does is to set `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` to `false`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I got too carried away :)
Very weird that JsonContractResolver is internal, it could be of some use if it was public and overrideable!

Comment: There is nothing to override inside it man. It is plain useless.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question now, but if anyone else is interested I managed to get around this by creating an [IsNotEmpty] annotation.

This uses reflection to work out whether there's an implementation of Empty on the property, and if so compares it. This then gets picked up at model validation time, not when the JSON is being parsed.

```
public class IsNotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        if (value == null) return false;

        var valueType = value.GetType();
        var emptyField = valueType.GetField("Empty");

        if (emptyField == null) return true;

        var emptyValue = emptyField.GetValue(null);

        return !value.Equals(emptyValue);

    }
}
```